# Disable filtering on a Dynamic Data list view

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data

I have an entity set of *NotificationTemplates*, and each one of these has a collection of zero-many *SmsTemplate* entities.  When editing or viewing a *NotificationTemplate*, I have a link to `View SMS Templates`.  That link takes me to a List view for the *SmsTemplates* entity set, filtered for the *NotificationTemplate* I was viewing.

How can I prevent the user changing this filter to show *SmsTemplates* for another *NotificationTemplate*?  That is, I want the filter, but it must be read only.  The drop-down just mustn't drop down, it must just display the name of the *NotificationTemplate* that these SmsTemplates belong to.  To view SmsTemplates for another *NotificationTemplate*, the user must click `View SMS Templates` from that other template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code-behind of the [filter template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee211433.aspx#filter_templates) is what tells the filter to pick up its value from the query string. It checks the [DefaultValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.dynamicdata.queryablefilterusercontrol.defaultvalue.aspx) property, and if set to a value, assigns that to the filter. What you want to do is add logic that makes the filter read-only when *DefaultValue* has a value . The simplest way to make it read-only this is to make the control disabled. Here's how you would do it for the default *ForeignKey.ascx.cs* implementation:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (!Column.IsRequired)
        {
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("[Not Set]", NullValueString));
        }
        PopulateListControl(DropDownList1);
        // Set the initial value if there is one
        string initialValue = DefaultValue;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(initialValue))
        {
            DropDownList1.SelectedValue = initialValue;
            DropDownList1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```